# Trying to use an action button to call function - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.2.4

I'm trying to add an action button in M1 dashboard.

I want the button to call the function I've created, and display a warning message.

The first snippet is what I started with and I'm struggling to get it working (second snippet).

I started off with this example:

```
<strong class="action_button">
<a class="icon_list preview_grid" title="<?php echo $this->__('Delete') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure want to delete').'?'; ?>')" 
href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . "booking/booking/delete/"; ?>id/<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"  ><?php echo $this->__('Delete') ?></a>
/strong>
```

and then modified a bit to get the below, but can't get it working.

perhaps someone can help. Many thanks

```
<strong class="action_button">
<a class="icon_list calender" target="_blank" title="Copy"  onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure want to copy').'?'; ?>')" 
href=$this->__<?php echo Mage::helper(‘function’)->Duplicate_frontend(); ?> ><?php echo $this->__('Copy') ?></a>
</strong>
```

Here is my function code:

Duplicate_frontend.xml:

```
<?xml version=“1.0”?>
<config>
<modules>
<Duplicate_frontend_Function>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</Duplicate_frontend_Function>
</modules>
</config>
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version=“1.0”?>
<config>
<modules>
<Duplicate_frontend_Function>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</Duplicate_frontend_Function>
</modules>
<global>
<helpers>
<function>
<class>Duplicate_Function_Helper</class>
</function>
</helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

Data.php:

```
class Duplicate_Function_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
public function Duplicate_frontend() //change the function name
{
$productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();
$productObject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $productObject->load($productId);
$newProduct = $_product->duplicate();
//new product status is disabled - to view in the frontend you will need to set the status as enabled
$newProduct->setStatus(1);
$newProduct->setName('Duplicate-' . $_product->getName());
$newProduct->setSku('value-' . $productId);
$newProduct->setWebsiteIds($_product->getWebsiteIds());
//set the product stock and qty to display product in the frontend
//while creating duplicate product, it will update the new product to have qty 0 and out of stock
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($newProduct->getId());
if ($stockItem->getId() > 0 && $stockItem->getManageStock())
{
$qty = 100;
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
$stockItem->save();
}
$newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);
//automate reindexing - to display the product in the frontend
$indexers = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
foreach ($indexers as $indexer)
{
$indexer->reindexEverything();
}
}
```

Revised action button code.
The function is performed upon page load (not good), 
Need to action the function upon click/confirm.
How should I change this code?

```
<strong class="action_button">
<a class="icon_list calender" target="_blank" title="Copy"  onClick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure want to copy').'?'; ?>')" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('DuplicateModule')->duplicatefunction(); ?>" ><?php echo $this->__('Copy') ?></a>
</strong>
```

Comment: I think I got the issue , can you provide me your full directory path  config.xml

Comment: Which config.xml would you like?
my app/etc/config.xml, or my theme config.xml, or different?

Just want to be sure I provide the correct file

Comment: your module confix.xml path

Comment: Ok, I think this is what you are asking for:
http://pastebin.com/HhjLvwde

I don't have a custom module exclusively for the function, just want to utilize the existing theme module.

Would I need to use a custom module?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Murtuza, I think I misunderstood what you were requesting.
The path of my module.xml is:
~/magento/app/code/local/Duplicate/Function/etc/config.xml

I hope that is the info you needed. Let me know otherwise

Comment: moved my code into the contoller (no longer need the helper), and modified the href to add the product id variable. 

`<a class="icon_list calender" target="_self" title="Copy" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you want to copy').'?'; ?>')" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . "duplicatelisting/duplicate/copy"; ?>/id/<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" ><?php echo $this->__('Copy') ?></a>`

Comment: I then added some validation code to the controller. As you can see I changed the module/folder structure name a bit as a result of testing etc. Was looking at using `_forward` but couldn't work it out, the extra variable on the end of the href did it. Also changed the `target` variable so it loads in the same page/tab. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second code snippet from

```
<strong class="action_button"> <a class="icon_list calender" target="_blank" title="Copy" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure want to copy').'?'; ?>')" href=$this->__<?php echo Mage::helper(‘function’)->Duplicate_frontend(); ?> ><?php echo $this->__('Copy') ?></a> </strong>
```

To

```
<strong class="action_button"> <a class="icon_list calender" target="_blank" title="Copy" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure want to copy').'?'; ?>')" href="<?php echo Mage::helper(‘function’)->Duplicate_frontend(); ?>" ><?php echo $this->__('Copy') ?></a> </strong>
```

There is a typo mistake in your `href`
**EDIT**
First, update your file name from **Duplicate_frontend.xml** to **Duplicate_Function.xml** and in that file update module name as `Duplicate_Function`
Same way in your **config.xml** update `Duplicate_frontend_Function` to `Duplicate_Function`
The thing you are doing wrong here is you are using your `helper` function directly in your `href` which is wrong,
Create a `controller` action and put controller action's url to your `href` data just like the example you have put from core Magento
In that controller action, call your helper function and your issue will get resolved.

```
<strong class="action_button"> <a class="icon_list calender" target="_blank" title="Copy" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure want to copy').'?'; ?>')" href="<?php echo YOUR_CONTROLLER_ACTION_PATH; ?>" ><?php echo $this->__('Copy') ?></a> </strong>
```

In your Controller file,
use below code

```
Mage::helper('function')->Duplicate_frontend();
```

Comment: Thanks Jaimin,
The function is called successfully, But, it is actioned upon page load, and not upon the click/confirm.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
code I am using is added above ^^

Comment: The function is being called on page load? There is no code in your question which works on page load, there is only a button and you have used its click event to run function. Are you sure this is the only code you have?

Comment: Hi Jaimin, I can't find what is wrong.
Yes the page is loading the function without waiting for the confirm.

In Chrome dev console, its shows the href a blank:
eg. 
                
`<a class="icon_list calender" target="_blank" title="Copy" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to copy?')" href="" >Copy</a>`


I guess the echo is loading the function, regardless of whether the button is clicked to confirm or not.
Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Please check my edit to the answer

Comment: Thanks Jaimin, I got it working!

ended up moving my code into the contoller (no longer need the helper), and modified the href to add the product id variable.

        
`<a class="icon_list calender" target="_self" title="Copy" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you want to copy').'?'; ?>')" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . "duplicatelisting/duplicate/copy"; ?>/id/<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" ><?php echo $this->__('Copy') ?></a>`

Comment: I then added some validation code to the controller.
As you can see I changed the module/folder structure name a bit as a result of testing etc.
Was looking at using `_forward`  but couldn't work it out, the extra variable on the end of the href did it.
Also changed the `target` variable so it loads in the same page/tab.
It is working perfectly.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

there were many things that is wrong in your code ,First I notice that your module file name is `Duplicate_frontend.xml`

instead of `Duplicate_Function.xml`

and code for that file would be.

```
<?xml version=“1.0”?>
<config>
<modules>
<Duplicate_Function>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</Duplicate_Function>
</modules>
</config>
```

and in your config.xml code would be

```
<?xml version=“1.0”?>
<config>
<modules>
<Duplicate_Function>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</Duplicate_Function>
</modules>
<global>
<helpers>
<function>
<class>Duplicate_Function_Helper</class>
</function>
</helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Murtuza, this was a big help. Got the function structure working, I now just have a problem with the when the function is loaded.

Comment: @Dan I am busy right now let you know full detail answer at tonight

Comment: Thanks for your help Murtuza, finally got it working.
I think the answer from Jaimin helped with finally getting it to do exactly what I needed.